# Annoying snag when moving with dx and dy JAVA

Tags: java, movement

I am currently using a keyAdapter with detectors and when I move I change the value of dx and dy respectively. However if I move left then right or up then down quickly, the sprite won't move in the direction I last input. Does anyone know a fix?

Detector method:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        dx = -1;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        dx = 1;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        dy = -1;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        dy = 1;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        dx = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        dx = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        dy = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        dy = 0;
    }
}
```

Move method:

```
public void move(){
    worldX+=dx;
    worldY+=dy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could decouple the button push and the delta move. In the key events, you can always set the button state

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
    leftPressed = true/false; // depending on press/release
}
...
```

Then later set deltas in the move method or a controls handler method (this will stop x movement if both left and right are pressed -1 and +1 to the delta):

```
public void move(){
  dx = 0;
  dy = 0;

  if (leftPressed) {
    dx -= 1;
  }
  if (rightPressed) {
    dx += 1;
  }
  ...

  worldX+=dx;
  worldY+=dy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

guessing keyreleased come after changing direction, try :

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
    if (dx==-1)
    dx = 0;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
    if (dx==1)
    dx = 0;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
    if (dy==-1)
    dy = 0;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
   if (dy==1)
    dy = 0;
}
```